# Emacs ignores .Xresources

Tags: emacs

I have some settings in `.Xresources` for emacs. Namely:

```
Emacs.font: Monospace-10:antialias=True:pixelsize=14
Emacs.menuBar: off
Emacs.toolBar: off
Emacs.verticalScrollBars: off
```

This worked fine on 11.10. But in 12.04, the toolbars are back! Noooo! What's going on?

I tried moving the settings to `.Xdefaults` but that didn't work. I tried changing `Emacs` to `Emacs23` as I saw suggested somewhere. Nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to use `Emacs23` instead of `Emacs`. For this to take effect I needed to restart X. (Or you can just run 'xrdb -merge .Xresource' so the changes will take effect immediately)

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but [this link should help](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/emacs-faq.html#Emacs-ignores-X-resources)